# NullReferenceExn when initializing object, but only if Lambda expression present (in C#)

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, nullreferenceexception

I have the following bizarre situation: `Pair` is a value type holding a `Widget` and an `Int32` , and `GetNonNullWidget()` returns a particular non-null `Widget`. `List<Pair> lstWidgetsAndNumbers` is a list.

The following code throws a null reference exception *when initialising the local variable*:

EDITED:

```
Widget widgetX = null;        //this throws a NulLRefExn

widgetX = GetNonNullWidget();

var pairX = lstWidgetsAndNumbers.Find(pair => pair.First == widgetX);     //but only if this line exists.
```

The locals window in VisulStudio2008 shows  `widgetX` with a red warning, and the message
" '' is null ".

If I encapsulate the third line with the lambda in a method, then everything works fine.

I clearly understand lambdas even less than I thought I did; can anyone explain what is going on here?? Thanks!

EDIT:

To be clear: `GetNonNullWidget()` returns a `Widget`, and it is non-null as can be checked while debugging.

Comment: Based on the description, there is a bug in `GetNonNullWidget`.

Comment: It seems like either your description isn't complete, or the debugger is acting up. Are your breakpoints hit properly and such? Otherwise try rebuilding your solution/restarting visual studio.

Comment: As a sidenote ... the `as` operator should never throw a `NullReferenceException`, that's why I believe according to your current description something is wrong with the debugger.

Comment: The only reason I get an Object and then cast was to localize the error. Initially I just set Widget widgetX = GetNonNullWidget(); So it's not the "as" throwing the exception, its the initialisation itself.

Comment: OK, edited to get rid of the confusung cast!

Comment: Could you provide constructor(s) of Widget? == operator?

Comment: It just checks each property for equals. It doesn't get called anyway...

Comment: In VS2012 I have suggestion: 

> "Possible uninitiated reference comparison; to get a value comparison cast left hand side to type "Widget"." Try to cast (Widget)pair.First. And what about Object.Equals(object o)? I suppose that full Widget code can help. Could you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

[The `as` operator should never throw a NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), that's why I believe according to your current description something is wrong with the debugger.

Verify the following:

- Are you debugging a `Debug` build?
- [Is the 'Optimize code' checkbox unchecked in the build properties?](http://joelblogs.co.uk/2010/02/10/visual-studio-2008-%E2%80%93-when-debugging-highlights-the-wrong-line/)

If all this is correct try one or more of the following:

- Do a rebuild of your solution.
- Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the cast. The exception occurs on initializing the variable.

Comment: @JoelinGö: `Widget widgetX = null;` should never throw an exception either.

Comment: - Optimize Code is NOT checked

Comment: Restarted VS and rebuilt the solution. Still same problem.

Comment: @JoelinGö: Well, clearly that shouldn't happen, so I'd try to eliminate as much as possible from your solution, trying to recreate the problem with a minimum amount of code. Either you have just found a bug, or you'll be able to pinpoint the problem that way. In case it's a bug you can report it [on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) as such. Good luck!

Comment: I had the same issue today - the line "int fid = 0" was causing a NullRefEx, and for the life of me couldn't figure out why. It was a web JIt-compiled project with a web service.